# Can't round all corners of a UIViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to round all the corners of a UIViewController. In my view controller I have the following:

```
 override func viewDidLoad()
  {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    maskLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: view.bounds, byRoundingCorners: .AllCorners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)).CGPath
    view.layer.mask = maskLayer
    let margin = CGFloat(10)
    self.view.frame = CGRect(x: margin, y: margin, width: view.frame.size.width - margin*2, height: view.frame.size.height - margin * 2)
  }
```

In the view controller that presents the above controller I have:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Subscriptions", bundle: nil)
let subscriptionsViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("subscriptionsViewController") as! SubscriptionsViewController
addChildViewController(subscriptionsViewController)
view.insertSubview(subscriptionsViewController.view, aboveSubview: view)
subscriptionsViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
```

This presents the new controller fine however only the top left corner is rounded and non of the others. Any ideas what I might be doing wrong here? thanks!

Comment: I suspect that `self.view.frame` won't be set to the actual screen dimensions in `viewDidLoad` because the view is not yet attached to a superview.  Move your corner rounding code into another function and then call this function after `insertSubview`

Comment: @Paulw11 tried that just now and no luck I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2):

**Here you posted the incorrect question!** 
Because`**cornerRadius**`  is a property of a `CALayer`, which is associated with a `UIView`. A view controller can't have one, but it's view property can have.

As it is - just try on 
in Objective-C(make the same in Swift):

```
yourViewControllerToPresent.view.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0f//floatValue;
yourViewControllerToPresent.view.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the same for superview's  (self.veiw.superview.layer) property cornerRadius and masksToBounds.

If you have viewcontroller in navigation controller then set the same for it as well (self.navigationController.view.superview.layer)

Set the above in viewDidAppear of view controller